# What kind of dish/pastry consists of white bread with ice-cream or some sort of mousse inside?

Tags: bread, food-identification, pastry

I found this randomly: [image]

To me, it distinctively looks like non-sugary bread. It looks like the kind of bun you normally use for making sandwiches, for example put butter and/or cheese inside. It doesn't look like it's "sugary" and intended for being a pastry.

Is this a famous/known "dish"/product/concept?

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly [Brioche con Gelato](https://medium.com/@michaelburbella/this-sicilian-ice-cream-sandwich-replaces-your-predictable-breakfast-bb97886e6d14), which is [Brioche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brioche), a sweet and rich bread with [gelato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelato) a rich ice-cream made with whole milk and sugar.